# What is "Phoenix/Moneybookers" module for?

Tags: magento-1, third-party-module

Is there any special reason that there is one module installed in community folder by default?

```
app\code\community\Phoenix\Moneybookers
```

Just found one line in `Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Help_Mapping` `$_moduleMappings`

```
'system_config/edit/section/moneybookers' => 'payment/gateways.html',
```

... that is used in `Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::setPageHelpUrl()`

Is it used anywhere? Does somebody use it? Can I remove w/o doubt?

Comment: Aside from the functionality of the module, consider it included as an example for how to implement a custom payment module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an extension for Skrill (aka Moneybooker) Payment Gateway that allows to payments and money transfers to be made through the internet. So if you are not using that payment gateway you can disable this module.

For more information you can can checkout below links

https://github.com/simkea/Phoenix_Moneybookers 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skrill